# datatype text in mysql (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, types

In development I used sqlite3 and I was writing a blog application. So for the blog articles, I had datatype text which worked fine. I was able to write really long articles, never had a problem. Switch over to production using MySQL and now my articles are getting truncated after around 250 characters.

Does anyone know what I need to do and/or change to get MySQL to behave like sqlite3 was, allowing really large bodies of text?

Thank you.

db/schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110307222323) do

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "url"
  end
end
```

Comment: show us some code and mysql table dump, please.

Comment: Are you using `t.string :your_field` instead of `t.text :your_field` in the migration file?

Comment: wow, so sorry to waste your guys time, i had just recently rewrote the app, and made that mistake second time around. Soooo sorry guys, thanks anyways though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you should replace

```
t.string   :body
```

with

```
t.text   :body
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is right, Rails treats a "string" as a "varchar(255)" for mysql.  Using "text" will allow more characters.

Answer (score 0):

You must to change:

```
 t.text :body #change here
```

You can find more information about data type comparisons [here](http://blog.ifyouseewendy.com/blog/2015/08/10/data-types-in-rails/)